# How To Pre-Find A Command's Impact?

Tags: command

RPM & Yum could be helpful tool to find the new files that can be added after a pkg installation. But being a system admin in a world of ever-changing system files & data due to fast pace of booming-technology, and knowing how every command or a new query will affect system files, is (..in my opinion atleast) a necessary skill. So My Quetions is:

Is there a way to find out the impact of a any command we type or about to type prior it's execution? I mean that would be nice, let's say I use:

```
useradd newUser
```

now we all linux tick-tac(k)-ers have a general idea of what this command is going to do. But commands can get long & complex sometimes. So is there a way to find what changes would any command make to a system?

```
pre-flight useradd newUser
```

I'm using *pre-flight* as a fictional name for a tool, that will best suit my criterion.

It should summarize something like this:

1. Adds 'newUser:x:1001:1001::/home/newUser:/bin/bash' line to
   /etc/passwd
2. Sets newUser primary Groups as newUser & adds 'newUser:x:1001' line
   to /etc/groups
3. Creates newUser's homedir as /home/newUser & maildir as
   /var/spool/mail/

You get the idea:

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can check all the code, they're all assembly in some form, then use your brain and Intel manual to analyze what will happen if you run that code. I don't get the idea, you just list the things that `useradd` would do and you're interested in, not all those tons of background things it will also do but you're not interested.

Comment: In the ideal world, what man page tells is what you are interested in. But we're not living in utopia. You have complex human mind and computer system have complex implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a think exists in its entirety (as it would require quite some hooks to do). You can have a VM with snapshots and try what commands do there.

Or perhaps [ExplainShell](https://explainshell.com/) service might be helpful, although it only shows you the docs for your command and not the "full output you expect"

Comment: But a VM snapshot obviously can't snapshot every single state of that VM. You can't even define what is desired to be recorded because you as a human are too comfortable with the high level abstraction provided by your hardware and software and therefore are not able to precisely describe what state you're interested in.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 not easily, no. But it might be a way to compare files and file-contents...